# “main thread is not in main loop” in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I have variables with paths for GIF files on my computer and in the main() loop a class for GIF to run in a loop and a Worker class.
Also executing it from cmd prompt.

Execution of this program should simply print 8 times that the type of fruit you chose is nice and show GIF of it in Tkinter, when you input 'ok' GIF should quit and program awaits next input (another fruit) to do the same thing.

Everything is fine until the second attempt..that is,it prints out 8 times that fruit is nice BUT no GIF to show.If you input 'ok' it reports

> 'Exception in thread Thread'

and

> 'RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop' errors.

AnimatedGIF class code i downloaded from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580708-tkinter-animated-gif/  but i found that only half of it works fine for the GIF to go loop so i chopped part of it.

Guess i need Queue module or threading after() method but i don't know to implement them.

```
#! python3

fruit = [ 'apple', 'peach', 'orange', 'grape', 'lemon', 'banana', 
'strawberry', 'coconut' ]

app = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Apple.gif"
pea = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Peach.gif"
ora = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Orange.gif"
gra = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Grape.gif"
lem = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Lemon.gif"
ban = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Banana.gif"
stw = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Strawberry.gif"
coc = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder za python fajlove\Coconut.gif"

GIF = [ app, pea, ora, gra, lem, ban, stw, coc ]

def main():
        print('Enter the type of fruit you like to see')
        inpuT = input()

        while inpuT not in fruit:
                print('Enter the type of fruit you like to see')
                inpuT = input()

        a = fruit.index(inpuT)

        for x in fruit:
                print( fruit[a] + ' is nice!!!') 


        import tkinter as tk
        from tkinter import PhotoImage                                              
        from tkinter import Label
        import threading
        from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#-----------------------------------------------------------
        class AnimatedGIF(Label, object):
            def __init__(self, master, path, forever=True):
                self._master = master
                self._loc = 0
                self._forever = forever

                self._is_running = False

                im = Image.open(path)
                self._frames = []
                i = 0
                try:
                    while True:
                        photoframe = 
ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy().convert('RGBA'))
                        self._frames.append(photoframe)

                        i += 1
                        im.seek(i)
                except EOFError: pass

                self._last_index = len(self._frames) - 1

                try:
                    self._delay = im.info['duration']
                except:
                    self._delay = 100

                super(AnimatedGIF, self).__init__(master, 
image=self._frames[0])

            def start_animation(self, frame=None):
                if self._is_running: return

                if frame is not None:
                    self._loc = 0
                    self.configure(image=self._frames[frame])

                self._master.after(self._delay, self._animate_GIF)

            def _animate_GIF(self):
                self._loc += 1
                self.configure(image=self._frames[self._loc])

                if self._loc == self._last_index:
                    if self._forever:
                        self._loc = 0
                        self._callback_id = 
self._master.after(self._delay, self._animate_GIF)

                else:
                    self._callback_id = self._master.after(100, 
self._animate_GIF)   

            def pack(self, start_animation=True, **kwargs):
                if start_animation:
                    self.start_animation()

                super(AnimatedGIF, self).pack(**kwargs)


        class Worker(threading.Thread):                    
                def run(self):
                        global root                        
                        root = tk.Tk()                     
                        win = AnimatedGIF(root, GIF[a])    
                        win.pack()                         
                        root.mainloop()

        w = Worker()                                       
        w.start()
        novo = input()
        if novo == 'ok':
                root.quit()

while True:
        main()
```

Comment: It would be best if you could make an example that doesn't rely on us downloading a bunch of images. Can you reproduce the problem by iterating over strings rather than animating an image?

Comment: Completely understand you..not that i overlooked it but since the problem is same for even just two GIFs i hope someone would just try it with his own random files.

Comment: The thing is i think i wouldn't be able to apply solution for strings iteration to animation example simply because i am noob.I don't understand even class that runs that animation in loop (functions that manipulate frames i presume).